# SQL and optional sorting ASC / DESC

Tags: postgresql

I know how to add an optional parameters to an sql query

it is done like this

```
select * from test t where (?1 is null or t.myColumn = ?1)
```

where `?1` is a parameter which you can pass from language
such as java (i.e using named queries), the advantage is that I don't
need to use ORM nor I need manually build (concatenate) strings into
query.

is there anything similar to make `ASC` and `DESC` optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will have to use dynamic SQL (statements constructed on the fly) for that.

There is a trick you could use for numeric columns:

```
... ORDER BY col * CASE WHEN $1 = 'DESC' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
```